# What does it mean to have an index to scalar variable error? python

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

with open('matrix.txt', 'r') as f:
    x = []
    for line in f:
        x.append(map(int, line.split()))
f.close()

a = array(x)

l, v = eig(a)

exponent = array(exp(l))

L = identity(len(l))

for i in xrange(len(l)):
    L[i][i] = exponent[0][i]

print L
```

1. My code opens up a text file containing a matrix:
   `1 2`
   `3 4`
   and places it in list `x` as integers.
2. The list `x` is then converted into an array `a`.
3. The eigenvalues of `a` are placed in `l` and the eigenvectors are placed in `v`.
4. I then want to take the exp(a) and place it in another array `exponent`.
5. Then I create an identity matrix `L` of whatever length `l` is.
6. My for loop is supposed to take the values of `exponent` and replace the 1's across the diagonal of the identity matrix but I get an error saying

   > `invalid index to scalar variable`.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: post the traceback please :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`exponent` is a 1D array. This means that `exponent[0]` is a scalar, and `exponent[0][i]` is trying to access it as if it were an array.

Did you mean to say:

```
L = identity(len(l))
for i in xrange(len(l)):
    L[i][i] = exponent[i]
```

or even

```
L = diag(exponent)
```

?

Answer (score 9):

`IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable` happens when you try to index a `numpy` scalar such as `numpy.int64` or `numpy.float64`. It is very similar to `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` when you try to index an `int`.

```
>>> a = np.int64(5)
>>> type(a)
<type 'numpy.int64'>
>>> a[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
>>> a = 5
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> a[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: @hoangtran, to fix it you have to fix your code. There is no meaningful result that `5[2]` can give you. Somewhere, you think that an array has 1 more dimension than it really does.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting this error because I had an input named `x` and I was creating (without realizing it) a local variable called `x`. I thought I was trying to access an element of the input `x` (which was an array), while I was actually trying to access an element of the local variable `x` (which was a scalar).