# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable for double 'for' statement

Tags: python, for-loop

My purpose is to calculate the list of certain variable repetitively using for statement inside of for statement.

My code is as follows.

```
for b in range(0,1487):
    c = 18000*b
    alpha = np.arctan(np.mean(v[c:c+18000])/np.mean(u[c:c+18000]))
    beta = np.arctan(np.mean(w[c:c+18000])/np.mean(u[c:c+18000]))
    R01 = R01.reshape((3,3))

    for c1 in range(c,c+18000):
            windvector = np.array([u[c1],v[c1],w[c1]])
            WV = windvector.reshape((3,1))
            m = np.dot(R01,WV)
            m = m.reshape((1,3))
            m = list(m)
            M = M + m
    for c2 in range(0,18000):
            u = M[c2][0]

            A = A + [u]
    m1 = np.mean(A[0:3000])
    m2 = np.mean(A[3000:3000*2])
    m3 = np.mean(A[3000*2:3000*3])
    m4 = np.mean(A[3000*3:3000*4])
    m5 = np.mean(A[3000*4:3000*5])
    m6 = np.mean(A[3000*5:3000*6])

    M = [m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6]

    s1 = np.std(A[0:3000])
    s2 = np.std(A[3000:3000*2])
    s3 = np.std(A[3000*2:3000*3])
    s4 = np.std(A[3000*3:3000*4])
    s5 = np.std(A[3000*4:3000*5])
    s6 = np.std(A[3000*5:3000*6])

    S = [s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6]

    RN = fabs((np.mean(S)-np.std(A))/np.std(A))

    RNT = RNT + [RN]
```

As shown in the code, I would like to get 1487 RN values repetitively, but when I ran this code,
this stopped just after 1 rotation among expected 1487, showing the error message of  "File "RN_stationarity.py", line 25, in  alpha = np.arctan(np.mean(v[c:c+18000])/np.mean(u[c:c+18000])) IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable."

I am not sure why I got this kind of error. I tried few solution in stackoverflow, but it didn't work.

Would you please give some idea or help?

It will be really appreciated.

Thank you,

Isaac

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594507/what-does-it-mean-to-have-an-index-to-scalar-variable-error-python - 
It just means u and/or v are scalar variables i.e. you can't index into them. Try to print their values, before line 25, and you'll see the problem for yourself.

Comment: In fact, you can see where `u` comes from: `u = M[c2][0]`. So `u` is obviously going to have a dimension two less than `M`, and `M` seems to be a 2D array based on the fact that you're adding `(1, 3)` arrays to it… so what did you expect `u[c:c+18000]` to mean if `u` is just a single value?

Comment: @Saish, Thank you for comment. I will try as you advise.

Comment: @abarnert, total number of data is 1487*18000 and I would like to separate the data in interval size of 18000.So, each u should have 18000 number of data. Thank you abarnet.

Comment: @Isaac: So if you have a 1487*18000 array, and you select one cell out that array by doing `[c2][0]`, how big is that one cell?

Comment: @abarnert: One cell would be just one value. M has three value in one list such as [1.5,0.5,0.1]. I would like to pick just one value of u by M[c2][0] and repeat same process 18000 time by for statement to make the list of 18000 u values. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: @Isaac: OK, if `u` has just one value, how are you going to extract 18000 values out of it? There aren't 18000 values there, just 1.

Comment: @abarnert: u should have total 1487*18000 numbers which I already  checked. I tried to divide this ino 1487 sets of 18000 value. So, each set of u,v,w should have 18000 numbers.

Comment: @Isaac: OK, I think I may have figured out what you're missing. Let me write an answer. However, you really need to put all of the answers to the questions people are asking you ***in the question***, not in comments. Explain what each of these variables are, what shape they have, and how you know that, and the question makes sense. Without that, there is no way to answer anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you use the name `u` for two completely different values. At the start of this loop, it's a nice big array, but in the middle of the loop you reassign it to a scalar, hence the `IndexError` when you try to index it the next time through the loop.

---

From the comments:

> `u` should have total 1487*18000 numbers which I already checked

So, that's how I know it starts off valid.

But then in the middle of the loop:

```
for c2 in range(0,18000):
        u = M[c2][0]

        A = A + [u]
```

From other comments, `M` is a 2D array. So, after this loop, `u` is a 0D array (that is, a scalar).

---

The solution is to just not use the name `u` for two unrelated things. Rename one of them to something else.

More generally, the solution is to not use meaningless one-letter variable names, because when you do that, it's very hard to avoid accidentally reusing one, and also hard to tell when you've done so.

Comment: Thank you very much abarnert, Now I can figure out what the problem is. I appreciate your help and patient again.