# How to fix IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

This code generates error:

```
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

at the line: `results.append(RMSPE(np.expm1(y_train[testcv]), [y[1] for y in y_test]))`

How to fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import ensemble
from sklearn import cross_validation

def ToWeight(y):
    w = np.zeros(y.shape, dtype=float)
    ind = y != 0
    w[ind] = 1./(y[ind]**2)
    return w

def RMSPE(y, yhat):
    w = ToWeight(y)
    rmspe = np.sqrt(np.mean( w * (y - yhat)**2 ))
    return rmspe

forest = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10, min_samples_split=2, n_jobs=-1)

print ("Cross validations")
cv = cross_validation.KFold(len(train), n_folds=5)

results = []
for traincv, testcv in cv:
    y_test = np.expm1(forest.fit(X_train[traincv], y_train[traincv]).predict(X_train[testcv]))
    results.append(RMSPE(np.expm1(y_train[testcv]), [y[1] for y in y_test]))
```

`testcv` is:

```
[False False False ...,  True  True  True]
```

Comment: What is the expected value of y[1] in the last line? You are iterating over y_test values, what's an example value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594507/what-does-it-mean-to-have-an-index-to-scalar-variable-error-python

Comment: @Monkey: y_test values: [ 6175.36384809  6267.20711569  5783.46657446 ...,  4323.34539658
  4332.18318557  3481.93371173]

Comment: `y_test` is 1d; you can't both iterate and index.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are trying to index into a scalar (non-iterable) value:

```
[y[1] for y in y_test]
#  ^ this is the problem
```

When you call `[y for y in test]` you are iterating over the values already, so you get a single value in `y`.

Your code is the same as trying to do the following:

```
y_test = [1, 2, 3]
y = y_test[0] # y = 1
print(y[0]) # this line will fail
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to get into your results array, but you need to get rid of `[y[1] for y in y_test]`.

If you want to append each y in y_test to results, you'll need to expand your list comprehension out further to something like this:

```
[results.append(..., y) for y in y_test]
```

Or just use a for loop:

```
for y in y_test:
    results.append(..., y)
```

Comment: Man this was a life-saver! Solved a similar problem for me which had put me on the verge of tears!

Answer (score 28):

**YOLO Object Detection**

`layer_names = net.getLayerNames() output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]`

Don't need to indexing **i** in **layer_names[i[0] - 1]**  . Just remove it and do **layer_names[i - 1]**

`layer_names = net.getLayerNames() output_layers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]`

**It Work For Me**

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was getting same error, the solution you mentioned worked for me as well

Answer (score 4):

**YOLO Object Detection**

*python <= 3.7*

```
ln = net.getLayerNames()
ln = [ln[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
```

*python >3.7*

```
ln = net.getLayerNames() 
ln = [ln[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `1` is not a valid index of `y`. If the visitor is coming from his own code he should check if his `y` contains the index which he tries to access (in this case the index is `1`).

Answer (score 0):

In the for, you have an iteration, then for each element of that loop which probably is a scalar, has no index. When each element is an empty array, single variable, or scalar and not a list or array you cannot use indices.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the yolo_video.py file in repo is required for those who are using darknet code.`This file works, replaced with required edits

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os
# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True,
    help="path to input video")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True,
    help="path to output video")
ap.add_argument("-y", "--yolo", required=True,
    help="base path to YOLO directory")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", type=float, default=0.3,
    help="threshold when applyong non-maxima suppression")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the COCO class labels our YOLO model was trained on
labelsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "biscuits.names"])
LABELS = open(labelsPath).read().strip().split("\n")    
# initialize a list of colors to represent each possible class label
np.random.seed(42)
COLORS = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(len(LABELS), 3),
    dtype="uint8")
# derive the paths to the YOLO weights and model configuration
weightsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "yolov4-custom_best.weights"])
configPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "yolov4-custom.cfg"])
# load our YOLO object detector trained on COCO dataset (80 classes)
# and determine only the *output* layer names that we need from YOLO
print("[INFO] loading YOLO from disk...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(configPath, weightsPath)

ln = net.getLayerNames()
print("ln",net)
ln = [ln[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

# initialize the video stream, pointer to output video file, and
# frame dimensions
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["input"])
writer = None
(W, H) = (None, None)
# try to determine the total number of frames in the video file
try:
    prop = cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT if imutils.is_cv2()\
        else cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT
    total = int(vs.get(prop))
    print("[INFO] {} total frames in video".format(total))
# an error occurred while trying to determine the total
# number of frames in the video file
except:
    print("[INFO] could not determine # of frames in video")
    print("[INFO] no approx. completion time can be provided")
    total = -1



# loop over frames from the video file stream
while True:
    # read the next frame from the file
    (grabbed, frame) = vs.read()
    # if the frame was not grabbed, then we have reached the end
    # of the stream
    if not grabbed:
        break
    # if the frame dimensions are empty, grab them
    if W is None or H is None:
        (H, W) = frame.shape[:2]
        # construct a blob from the input frame and then perform a forward
    # pass of the YOLO object detector, giving us our bounding boxes
    # and associated probabilities
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1 / 255.0, (416, 416),
        swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    start = time.time()
    layerOutputs = net.forward(ln)
    end = time.time()
    # initialize our lists of detected bounding boxes, confidences,
    # and class IDs, respectively
    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    classIDs = []
# loop over each of the layer outputs
    for output in layerOutputs:
        # loop over each of the detections
        for detection in output:
            # extract the class ID and confidence (i.e., probability)
            # of the current object detection
            scores = detection[5:]
            classID = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[classID]
            # filter out weak predictions by ensuring the detected
            # probability is greater than the minimum probability
            if confidence > args["confidence"]:
                # scale the bounding box coordinates back relative to
                # the size of the image, keeping in mind that YOLO
                # actually returns the center (x, y)-coordinates of
                # the bounding box followed by the boxes' width and
                # height
                box = detection[0:4] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
                (centerX, centerY, width, height) = box.astype("int")
                # use the center (x, y)-coordinates to derive the top
                # and and left corner of the bounding box
                x = int(centerX - (width / 2))
                y = int(centerY - (height / 2))
                # update our list of bounding box coordinates,
                # confidences, and class IDs
                boxes.append([x, y, int(width), int(height)])
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                classIDs.append(classID)
    # apply non-maxima suppression to suppress weak, overlapping
    # bounding boxes
    idxs = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, args["confidence"],
        args["threshold"])
    # ensure at least one detection exists
    if len(idxs) > 0:   
        # loop over the indexes we are keeping
        for i in idxs.flatten():
            # extract the bounding box coordinates
            (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
            (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])
            # draw a bounding box rectangle and label on the frame
            color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[classIDs[i]]]
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
            text = "{}: {:.4f}".format(LABELS[classIDs[i]],
                confidences[i])
            cv2.putText(frame, text, (x, y - 5),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2)
    # check if the video writer is None
    if writer is None:
        # initialize our video writer
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
        writer = cv2.VideoWriter(args["output"], fourcc, 30,
            (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), True)
        # some information on processing single frame
        if total > 0:
            elap = (end - start)
            print("[INFO] single frame took {:.4f} seconds".format(elap))
            print("[INFO] estimated total time to finish: {:.4f}".format(
                elap * total))
    # write the output frame to disk
    writer.write(frame)
# release the file pointers
print("[INFO] cleaning up...")
writer.release()
vs.release()`
```