# String concatenation/indexing giving IndexError

Tags: python

I am attempting some relatively basic string concatenation, but can't seem to find the source of the error I am receiving.

My code is as follows:

```
def crossover(dna1, dna2):
    """
    Slices both dna1 and dna2 into two parts at a random index within their
    length and merges them.
    """
    pos = int(random.random()*DNA_SIZE)
    return (dna1[:pos]+dna2[pos:], dna2[:pos]+dna1[pos:])
```

Later, I reference this function in the following way, where the variables `ind1Aff` and `ind2Aff` have been previously defined as **binary strings**:

```
ind1Aff, ind2Aff = crossover(ind1Aff, ind2Aff)
```

However, when running my code, **I get the following error**:

```
    return (dna1[:pos]+dna2[pos:], dna2[:pos]+dna1[pos:])
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I have attempted to change it slightly to things like `dna1[0:pos]+dna2[pos:DNA_SIZE]` (where DNA_SIZE is the length of the strings), etc., but to no prevail. There are sources with the same issue like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978575/how-to-fix-indexerror-invalid-index-to-scalar-variable/32979196), but they don't seem to help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ... Are you sure those are strings? I've never seen that error before when using built-in types.

Comment: try some sample values for `dna1` and `dna2`. They're certainly not strings.

Comment: What are the values you are passing in place of ind1Aff and ind2Aff?

Comment: The values used were binary strings, so one of the values is something like `1010001100001000`.

Comment: Can you check the `type` of your binary strings? Are you sure it's a string and not some other custom data structure?

Comment: Oh... I see. The type of these are `<numpy.float64>` values. I included a line with `ind1Aff = str(ind1Aff)` and it solved the issue. Sorry for such a basic issue!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems the most likely issue is you are not in fact passing in a string. Try printing the type (i.e. type(dna1)) before the split on the string is performed.

When you do pass a normal python string, your code works as expected:

```
import random


def crossover(dna1, dna2):
    """ 
    Slices both dna1 and dna2 into two parts at a random index within their
    length and merges them.
    """
    DNA_SIZE = len(dna1)
    pos = int(random.random()*DNA_SIZE)
    return (dna1[:pos]+dna2[pos:], dna2[:pos]+dna1[pos:])


def main():
    one = '000000000000000'
    two = '111111111111111'
    ind1Aff, ind2Aff = crossover(one, two)
    print ind1Aff
    print ind2Aff


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
000011111111111
111100000000000
```

You could also throw in str(dna1) and str(dna2) before applying string split.