# IndexError: invalid index to Scalar Variable. YOLO Project

Tags: python, opencv

```
 for i in indices:
        i=i[0]
        box=bbox[i]
        x,y,w,h=box[0],box[1],box[2],box[3]
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,255),2)
```

Output:
i=i[0]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978575/how-to-fix-indexerror-invalid-index-to-scalar-variable)