# i = i[0] leads to IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, opencv, mediapipe

Im getting an error every time i run this script in my environment

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FaceMark.py", line 55, in <module>
    i = i[0]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

The camera does turns on but as soon it detects my hand or face the camera windows shuts down and it throws me the error posted above.

here's the entire script:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time
import numpy as np

thres = 0.45  # Threshold to detect object
nms_threshold = 0.2`your text`
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
cap.set(3, 1280)
cap.set(4, 720)
cap.set(10, 150)

classNames = []
classFile = 'coco.names'
with open(classFile, 'rt') as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

configPath = 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
weightsPath = 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath, configPath)
net.setInputSize(320, 320)
net.setInputScale(1.0 / 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
pTime = 0
cTime = 0

mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mpFaceMesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh
faceMesh = mpFaceMesh.FaceMesh(max_num_faces=2)
drawSpec = mpDraw.DrawingSpec(thickness=1, circle_radius=2)

mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mpHands.Hands()
mpDrawHand = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img, confThreshold=thres)
    bbox = list(bbox)
    confs = list(np.array(confs).reshape(1, -1)[0])
    confs = list(map(float, confs))
    indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(bbox, confs, thres, nms_threshold)

    results = faceMesh.process(imgRGB)

    resultsHand = hands.process(imgRGB)

    for i in indices:
        i = i[0]

        box = bbox[i]
        # colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(box), 3))

        x, y, w, h = box[0], box[1], box[2], box[3]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, h + y), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
        cv2.putText(img, classNames[classIds[i][0] - 1].upper(), (box[0] + 10, box[1] + 30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        print("Objects Ids: ", classIds)

    if resultsHand.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for handLms in resultsHand.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for id, lm in enumerate(handLms.landmark):
                print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)

                cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 5, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

            mpDrawHand.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

    if results.multi_face_landmarks:
        for faceLms in results.multi_face_landmarks:
            mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, faceLms, mpFaceMesh.FACE_CONNECTIONS,
                                  drawSpec, drawSpec)
            for id, lm in enumerate(faceLms.landmark):`
                # print(lm)
                ih, iw, ic = img.shape
                x, y = int(lm.x * iw), int(lm.y * ih)
                print("Face id: ", id, x, y)

    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
    pTime = cTime
    cv2.putText(img, f'FPS: {int(fps)}', (20, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                3, (255, 0, 0), 3)
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

how can i solve the problem around the indexes loop? i have tried other solutions here in similar questions, but i havent had any luck.

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. debug your code, look for previous questions. here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72452031/indexerror-invalid-index-to-scalar-variable-yolo-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable i returns an integer value. This is not a list or tuple. If you change the for loop as follows, it will likely work.

```
for i in indices:
        box = bbox[i]
        # colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(box), 3))

        x, y, w, h = box[0], box[1], box[2], box[3]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, h + y), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
        cv2.putText(img, classNames[classIds[i] - 1].upper(), (box[0] + 10, box[1] + 30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        print("Objects Ids: ", classIds)
```

Comment: That was the issue. everything is working as expected. thanks